# How to match an expression exactly X or Y times, rather than a range of X-Y?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check these conditions on a string:

•   Value must be between 7 - 12 characters long

•   IF the first character is [0-9]

- The first 9 characters must be [0-9]
- The 10th character must be [A-Z] and the 11th + 12th must be [A-Z,0-9]

•   ELSE IF the first character is [A-Z]

- Up to the first 3 characters must be [A-Z], then there must be exactly 6 or 9 digits [0-9]

I am absolutely horrible with RegEx but I came up with these 3 and I *think* they do the job but I'm not 100% certain. I was hoping someone here who's better with them could take a look? I've tried testing a few values and it seems good but again I don't really know.

```
var regexNum = new RegExp("^[0-9]{9}[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2}");
var regexLetter1 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}");
var regexLetter2 = new RegExp("^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{9}");
```

I know you can list a quantifier range like `{6,9}` which would match 6, 7, 8 or 9 times but I wasn't sure if there was a way to exactly match two supplied values, which is why I have 2 separate expressions for the "ELSE" case described above.

**EDIT** Sorry, I was in fact misinformed. It can be anywhere between 7 - 12 characters long, not 7 **or** 12 characters. The rest of the conditions are correct, though.

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: you can write `"^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})?"

Comment: _Value must be exactly 7 or 12  characters long_ so when first is letter, so there could be up to 3 letters, but then there need to be 6 or 9 digits, how?

Comment: @m.cekiera Good point. I might be mistaken on *exactly* 7 or 12, I will have to double check. The specs I was given are poorly worded :(

Comment: The simple answer to your question is that yes, to match either n or m repetitions of something, you need to write `x{n}|x{m}`, there is no other syntax.

Comment: @torazaburo **Originally** I said it must be 7 or 12 total, and must be [A-Z]{1,3}(\d{6}|\d{9}), you are correct-- that is wrong on my part. Then I editted it to say between 7-12. That validates all conditions for [A-Z]{1,3}(\d{6}|\d{9})

Comment: Was the problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

its one of these:

```
"^\d{9}[A-Z][A-Z\d]{2}$|[A-Z]{1,3}(?:\d{9}|\d{6})$"

"^\d{9}[A-Z][A-Z\d]{0,2}$|[A-Z]{1,3}(?:\d{9}|\d{6})$"
```

and if case doesn't matter:

```
"^\d{9}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{2}$|[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?:\d{9}|\d{6})$"

"^\d{9}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]{0,2}$|[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?:\d{9}|\d{6})$"
```

Comment: Your expression miss [A|B] for choice

Comment: nowhere in his question did he mention anything about `[A|B]`

Comment: No I mean ^[\d{9}[A-Z]{1}[A-Z\d]{2}|[A-Z]{3}(?:\d{9}|\d{6})]

Comment: dude, do you even know how to write regex? that is invalid and i have no idea why you are trying to wrap it into a character class

Comment: No need, it works up to spec so far unless he changes criteria which he said he needs to double check

Comment: _Up to the first 3 characters must be [A-Z]_ so I think [A-Z]{3} it will not match correctly up to current spec

Comment: If it *must* be 12 chars long and the next 9 *must* be numbers, what do u suggest ?

Comment: Also notice the *must* in the sentence you posted. It may be a context error on his part

Comment: Editted post; it is 7 - 12 characters, not 7 **or** 12. The rest of the conditions are correct, however.

Comment: They both do for me... https://regex101.com/r/dN7fV5/1 https://regex101.com/r/gK4vW0/1

Comment: Very confused. On regex101.com yours seem to work. In Javascript + IE11, they do not seem to match almost any of the "ELSE" conditions in my original post.

Comment: If case doesn't matter, just use the "i" flag.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although if the objective is to just validate, there is not need for the `(?:`.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is requesting a single massive Regex to solve this problem, but I thought I might offer a different perspective.

A problem with Regex is that they're simply not human readable when too many rules are added to them. Whenever you find yourself asking yourself "does this crazy thing even work?" then it's likely an indication that you've crossed the "Regex threshold."

I'm not afraid of Regex, by any means – in fact, I think they're a great tool with many uses – but I try to avoid crossing that threshold when I can. This is because I care not only about solving the problem, but also about solving it in a maintainable and clear way. A clever one-line Regex might look cool and be concise, but those are maybe it's only virtues.

Ironically, your opening post clearly describes the algorithm you're trying to write using conditionals. Why not just do that?

For this sort of validation, I've found that a combination of checks on the string the most readable and maintainable code. One consequence to this approach is that you have a bit of extra LoC, but I think it's worth the extra clarity.

```
// The string must be 7 or 11 characters long
if (string.length !== 7 && string.length !== 11) {}

// Verify the next rule...
else if () {}
```

Comment: Would like to upvote this answer multiple times if possible.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo! I figured most people would downvote this, but I'm glad to know someone thinks I'm not crazy :)

Comment: It might be easier to read but honestly and maybe maintain, but I think it's much harder to code for. Am I going to iterate over every character and try to come up with even more verbose logic to try and match each possible condition / value?

Comment: @sab669, no, of course not. You can use smaller regular expressions within the conditionals to match those simpler rules. The point is not to avoid regular expressions altogether: that would be silly. The point is to avoid a giant regular expression that doesn't make any sense to anyone!

Answer (score -2):

### [`(^\d{9}[A-Z][A-Z\d]{2}$)|(^[A-Z]{3}\d{6}$)|(^[A-Z]{3}\d{9}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bE6jR8/4)

This follows **exactly** what you've mentioned, but there seems to be an ambiguity about the number of characters allowed, I shall update this answer once you have edited your question.

> Value must be exactly 7 or 12 characters long

If 7 is ok, then the rest of your conditions won't make any sense at all. You must update your question with the proper range.

Comment: Editted my post with confirmation, it must be 7 - 12 characters, not *exactly* 7 or 12.

Comment: This actually caused IE to crash for me. While debugging it popped up saying "unexpected quantifier" then when I hit Continue IE stopped responding.

Comment: @torazaburo I think `^[0-9]+\d{8}` checks if the first character is 0-9, and then the next 8 characters are digits. How that's different than `^[0-9]{9}` I don't know.

Comment: @sab669 It was working fine before, and it is working fine now. The inconsistency is wording is not big of an issue, I believe. I have made an edit.

Comment: @sab669 Hmm... don't know why it crashed. I have  edited my answer now, but the real question is "You are using IE?" ... lolwut?

Comment: @torazaburo _that escalated quickly_ ... simmer down sempai, you may use whatever browser you prefer. The code above  was and is still working... if only you followed that link... **sigh**

Comment: Regexp101 is buggy, it turns out. It fails to detect the error in `\d{8}+`, which was in your answers prior to the most recent edit. The error, of course, is that you can't have two quantifiers next to each other. regexpal does give an error, as do regextester and regexr. I guess the lesson is to not trust regexp101 until further notice. I've raised an issue at https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/349. By the way, the error can also be easily detected by simply pasting the regexp into the browser console.

Comment: @RenaeLider It's almost as if certain companies only support certain browsers for business specific software or something. And if you don't believe me on it not working, feel free to look at the screenshot I editted in my OP where it does not evaluate to true with the most basic condition I described.

Comment: @RenaeLider Also that should be [A-Z]{1,3} on your right hand expression of the pipe

Comment: It turns out that regex101 is not buggy--the invalid `\d{8}+` is correctly detected **if JS mode is selected**. So @RenaeLider, it seems when testing a JS regexp you should make sure to select the correct flavor on regex101.